# Call plugin page inside admin area in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, admin

I have created a menu in WordPress for a custom plugin, that works fine. 
Inside this plugin, I had a button (add button) that will call another page.
I'm not sure what is wrong, but, it's not possible to call another page.

Here the print screen:
[image]

[image]

When i click on "Adicionar" button:
[image]

Can someone help me?

Comment: chars "-" and "_" is different. On first screenshot "wabot-menu-sorteio", but inside href you have "wabot_sorteio_detail". Can you try to replace "wabot_sorteio_detail" -> "wabot-sorteio-detail"?

Comment: Yeah, same problem. I think that the problem is that the admin.php page don't know where is the wabot-sorteio-detail.php file in the disk. But, I can't find where register the file, something like that. :/

Comment: Ok, i figure it out! I just create a hidden sub-menu and called it! I will answer my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem.

I just create a hidden submenu for the button, and call the slug menu id on the ?page parameter, like this:

```
add_menu_page('Sorteios', 'Sorteios', 'manage_options', 'wabot-menu-sorteio', 'wabot_menu_sorteio_handle', 'dashicons-awards', 100);
add_submenu_page(null, 'Adicionar Sorteio', 'Adicionar Sorteio', 'manage_options', 'wabot-submenu-adicionar-sorteio', 'wabot_submenu_adicionar_sorteio_handle');
```

And call like this:

```
<a href="<?=admin_url("admin.php?page=wabot-submenu-adicionar-sorteio")?>"><button class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Adicionar</button></a>
```

Works fine!